# SharePoint Hosted App Navigation

Tags: navigation, sharepoint-hosted-app, visual-studio-2013

I have created a SharePoint Hosted App in Visual Studio 2013 and I am struggling to find a way to navigate to a page.

I currently want a button on the default.aspx page that will navigate to another page inside of the SharePoint Hosted App. I can have a button navigate successfully but it doesn't load the entire query string such as the HostWebUrl, AppWebUrl, ClientTag etc...

I have done a bit of research on this and read about using the Chrome Control but I somehow don't think this is what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some chunk of code for understanding your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the QueryString parameters using Javascript and append it to your target page URL on the button click event handler.

Please use below code as a starting point:

```
function onRedirectButtonclick()
{
    var queryString = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
     window.location.href = "/NextPage.aspx?" + queryString;
}
```